# How can I use pipes (FIFO) with my program in bash scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, mkfifo

What I try to do:

Create a pipe (FIFO).

Redirect output of the pipe to the stdin (&1).

Redirect input of the pipe to the 4th descriptor (&4).

Run my program (it should copy it's parent descriptors, pointing to my pipe).

Write something to &4 (FIFO input).

Have it read by my program (from FIFO output).

```
input_pipe=$(mktemp -u);

mkfifo $input_pipe;

exec 1<$input_pipe;

exec 4>$input_pipe;

rm $input_pipe; #this should not remove the pipe itself

my_program &

echo $'input to be read by my_program' >&4;

#my program's answer should appear in stdout
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stdin has file descriptor `0`, not `1`.